# Upgrading from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008R2 with RBS support

Tags: 2010, sql-server, upgrade, remote-blob-storage

I am looking at setting up SharePoint 2010 in our local test environment and our current test SQL Server is running SQL 2005. I am just wondering if it is possible to upgrade the database later to SQL 2008R2 and enable RBS or do I have to reconfigure SharePoint all over again with a new database in SQL 2008R2 in order to enable RBS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upgrade your SQL Server after you install SP 2010. You can even start off by using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express then upgrade to higher editions. But, your job is made easier if you start up with SQL 2008 R2, then install SP 2010.

Make sure you back up you databases before proceeding.